# swift 4 add a image literal to a string

Tags: swift, string, image-literals

I want to be able to add an image to a string with some text. There was an example video on headerViews and he included the data that had the images embedded in the string.

I am not sure how he did it.

Here is the data

```
Section(genre: " Superhero",
        movies: ["Guardians of the Galaxy", "The Flash", "The Avengers", "The Dark Knight"],
        expanded: false,
        subtitle: "Please select a movie"),
Section(genre: " Horror",
        movies: ["The Walking Dead", "Insidious", "Conjuring"],
        expanded: false,
        subtitle: "Please select a movie")
```

`Section` is a simple data structure:

```
struct Section {
    let genre: String!
    let movies: [String]!
    let expanded: Bool!
    let subtitle: String!    

    init(genre: String, movies: [String], expanded: Bool, subtitle: String){
    self.genre = genre
    self.movies = movies
    self.expanded = expanded
    self.subtitle = subtitle
}
```

I tried using #imageLiteral(resourceName) with some text afterwards like

```
" #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pos") + "a title" "
```

which is not syntactically correct.

How do I add an image before some text in a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not image literals; they are ordinary characters (if you regard [emoji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) as ordinary). Swift strings are unicode strings, so you are allowed to type an emoji character directly into a string literal.

Comment: There are many examples on this page of the documentation: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html

Comment: Well, you can attach an inline image to an attributed string. But that is not what you asked about.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: would it actually work when i assigned it to cell.textLabel?.text?

Comment: @steller No but it will work when you assign it to `cell.textLabel.attributedText`.

Comment: I did a search for "inline image to an attributed string." and combined with what maddy said i was able to get it to work. Thanks guys